# Why it doesn't change the content inside the file?

Tags: windows, powershell

this code supposed to look for all demo.txt in the disk and change them from "demo" to "demodemo997182625" and then check if the file has changed or not

```
$found = 0;
$notfound = 0;


foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Recurse -Filter demo.txt -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue )
{
  (Get-Content $file).Replace("demo","demo997182625") | Set-Content $file

   $x = (Get-Content $file).contain("demo997182625")


   if($x -eq $null){

  $found = 1 + $found;
  }

  else {

  $notfound = 1 + $notfound;
  
  }

}            
Write-Host "Changed" $found;
Write-Host "Not Changed" $notfound;
```

Comment: Do you have write permission for the files?

Comment: I am Admin on this machine, is there another step I must do or check before running the script?

Comment: Check if the files are set to read only.

Comment: Is ```.contain("demo997182625")
``` in your original code? That should probably be ```contains``` rather than ```contain```, although that might not fix the root problem…

Comment: Checked, they are not read only

Comment: despite it didn't fix the issue but because of this, I was getting a false success of the code, Thank you for that.

Comment: You can also try ```(Get-Content $file -Raw)``` which will read the file as a single string rather than an array of lines. If *that* doesn’t work, try adding some logging with ```write-host``` to output variable values, file contents, etc and work out where it’s behaving differently to your expectations - for example is it even actually processing your file? Is it finding the “demo” string correctly? Is the replaced value correct, etc. once you know exactly which line is failing it might be more obvious what the fix is…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few remarks on your code:

- the `.Replace()` and `.Contains()` string methods work case-sensitive, so `.Replace("demo","demo997182625")` won't find and replace "Demo". To have it work case-insensitively, use the `-replace` operator instead.
- updated files can be reprocessed by Get-ChildItem, unless you have that part finish completely first. The easiest way to do that is by enclosing it between brackets
- I would only save the file if there was something updated (i.e. the new value was found after `-replace`), otherwise leave it be
- Get-ChildItem returns both FileInfo and DirectoryInfo objects. Since you are interested in changing files only, append the -File switch
- best use the FullName property of the found file on the Get- and Set-Content cmdlets instead of the whole FileInfo object

```
$found = $notfound = 0

# surround the Get-ChildItem line with brackets, so it will finish before iterating on the result
# otherwise, it could reprocess files that were allready updated
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' -Recurse -Filter 'demo.txt' -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    # -replace uses regex, so surround the search string with '\b' boundary markers in order to do a whole-word search
    $content = (Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -Raw -Force) -replace '\bdemo\b', 'demo997182625'
    # test if the content now has the new value (again, use '\b' boundary markers)
    if ($content -match '\bdemo997182625\b') { 
        # save the updated file
        $content | Set-Content -Path $file.FullName -Force
        $found++ 
    } 
    else {$notfound++}

}            
Write-Host "Changed: $found"
Write-Host "Not Changed: $notfound"
```

P.S. If your search string contains characters that in regex have special meaning (see table below), you need to **escape** these with a backslash when using regex operators `-replace` and `-match`.

**Special Characters in Regex**

| Char | Description | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| \ | Backslash | Used to escape a special character |
| ^ | Caret | Beginning of a string |
| $ | Dollar sign | End of a string |
| . | Period or dot | Matches any single character |
| | | Vertical bar or pipe symbol | Matches previous OR next character/group |
| ? | Question mark | Match zero or one of the previous |
| * | Asterisk or star | Match zero, one or more of the previous |
| + | Plus sign | Match one or more of the previous |
| ( ) | Opening and closing parenthesis | Group characters |
| [ ] | Opening and closing square bracket | Matches a range of characters |
| { } | Opening and closing curly brace | Matches a specified number of occurrences of the previous |

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed explanation on how to solve such an issue, it worked.